# Does "./..." mean all subfolders?

Tags: file, go

I often see "./..." in makefile. I *think* it means it is all subfolders in the current directory. Could someone confirm and provide me the source where this syntax is explained?

Example:

```
go generate ./...
```

Comment: Can you provide me with the source of a makefile using `./...`?

Comment: Makefiles *are not bash* -- different language, different syntax, different tagging.

Answer (score 8):

The import path pattern `./...` matches all packages in directories below the current directory, except those in vendor directories.

The pattern is implemented by the `go` tool. The pattern is not interpreted by make, bash and any other tool that might invoke the `go` tool.

The [documentation for the go command says](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_package_lists):

> An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..." wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty string and strings containing slashes. Such a pattern expands to all package directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the patterns.
>
> To make common patterns more convenient, there are two special cases. First, /... at the end of the pattern can match an empty string, so that net/... matches both net and packages in its subdirectories, like net/http. Second, any slash-separated pattern element containing a wildcard never participates in a match of the "vendor" element in the path of a vendored package, so that ./... does not match packages in subdirectories of ./vendor or ./mycode/vendor, but ./vendor/... and ./mycode/vendor/... do. Note, however, that a directory named vendor that itself contains code is not a vendored package: cmd/vendor would be a command named vendor, and the pattern cmd/... matches it. See golang.org/s/go15vendor for more about vendoring.

and it [also says](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths_):

> An import path beginning with ./ or ../ is called a relative path. The toolchain supports relative import paths as a shortcut in two ways.
>
> First, a relative path can be used as a shorthand on the command line. If you are working in the directory containing the code imported as "unicode" and want to run the tests for "unicode/utf8", you can type "go test ./utf8" instead of needing to specify the full path. Similarly, in the reverse situation, "go test .." will test "unicode" from the "unicode/utf8" directory. Relative patterns are also allowed, like "go test ./..." to test all subdirectories. See 'go help packages' for details on the pattern syntax.
>
> Second, if you are compiling a Go program not in a work space, you can use a relative path in an import statement in that program to refer to nearby code also not in a work space. This makes it easy to experiment with small multipackage programs outside of the usual work spaces, but such programs cannot be installed with "go install" (there is no work space in which to install them), so they are rebuilt from scratch each time they are built. To avoid ambiguity, Go programs cannot use relative import paths within a work space.

Comment: @SteveHe, I'd stress that the `go build` and `go install` (and `go test`) invocations work on *go packages* rather than files (as opposed to `go run`). So the special construct `{path}/...` means "all the packages anchored as `{path}`, and that `{path}` is an *import path in a Go workspace.* The fact this spec makes the `go` tool traverse the hierarchy of directories is an implementation detail.